# Why I'm getting this "Character" errors using R joins in Jupyter to dataframes coming from tables source in Adventureworks2016 SQL Server?

Tags: r, jupyter-notebook

"Error in UseMethod("inner_join"): no applicable method for 'inner_join' applied to an object of class "character" Traceback: ..."

Here are my 3 data frame prep queries that I ran or executed successfully in R Jupyter environment:

sql_products <- "SELECT * FROM Production.Product"
sqlquery <- dbGetQuery(conn,sql_products)
sqlquery

sql_productsCatg <- "SELECT * FROM Production.ProductCategory"  # >> Bikes, Components, Clothing, Access.
sqlquery <- dbGetQuery(conn,sql_productsCatg)
sqlquery

sql_productsSub <- "SELECT * FROM Production.ProductSubCategory"
sqlquery <- dbGetQuery(conn,sql_productsSub)
sqlquery`

## below join data frame is getting the error I mentioned above:`

sql_prod_Join <- sql_productsCatg %>%
inner_join(sql_productsSub, by = "ProductCategoryID")
glimpse(sql_prod_Join)
`
Thanks in advance!

Tried to switch to other tables like SalesOrderHeader, SalesOrderDetail, joined them to create new data frames and it worked here:
`
sql_select <- "SELECT * FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader"
df_sales_order_header <- conn %>%
dbGetQuery(sql_select)

sql_select = "SELECT * FROM Sales.SalesOrderDetail"
df_sales_order_detail <- conn %>%
dbGetQuery(sql_select)`

## below join data frame ran successfully with no errors compared to (sql_prod_Join) above:

`df_sales_order_joins <- df_sales_order_header %>% inner_join(df_sales_order_detail, by = "SalesOrderID")`

Not sure even how to plot them next using ggplot, randomly picking any variable/column to visualize the data, please advise thanks.